# Simple proof of knowledge

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

It seems to me that signing the hash of the public key with ECDSA should be a sufficient non-interactive proof of knowledge.

In my use case, I only need the guarantee that "someone even had knowledge", not that the proof is linked to a specific transmitter.

Is there a good precedent for using ECDSA in this manner?

Since ECDSA is part of the openssl library, and ECDSA is, effectively, a proof of knowledge I though it would be better to choose this technique over building it from scratch.

Comment: What are you even trying to prove knowledge of?

Comment: Do you actually want zero-knowledge? You haven't referenced this anywhere in the question.
And when you say "not linked to a specific transmitter", do you want to enforce this level of anonymity?